# Handle Control in UserControl click

Tags: vb.net, events, user-controls

I made a user control, with a picture box and 2 labels. Whenever i click on any of the controls in the user control in a form, the user control click event does not happen. How can i do for when i click any of the labels or the picturebox the usercontrol.click event happens too?

The labels are "label1" and "label2", The picture box is named "pic1".
The usercontrol's name is "Tile".

Please Help!

I have tried something like event handling, using addhandler but it confuses me a little...

`Public Event ItemClicked()`

```
`Private Sub Pic1_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pic1.Click

    RaiseEvent ItemClicked()

End Sub`
```

But i'm stuck there, i don't know what else to do.

Comment: On a UserControl, the UserControl will get the clicks/events of its child controls, not the form.  (which is part of the point of putting them there).  Are the controls added in the designer or are you adding them in code?

Comment: It should be like that, i added them using the designer...

Comment: But whenever i click on the picturebox from the UserControl the form doesn't capture the click event

Comment: drill into the controls and make sure you have code in the event procedures (just like with a form, but they will be in the UC code)...`the form doesn't capture the click event ` read my first comment again closely: it is not supposed to

Comment: ok, i understand, but how can i do, in the usercontrol code, for the click events on the labels or picturebox, to do the same thing as the click event of the usercontrol??.. that way any control i click, will go to the usercontrol.click

Comment: *Usually* a UC represents some task like define Customer, DoSearch, AddAccount and the child controls are part of doing that task.  When all is done the UC might raise a new event like `SearchComplete` or `CustomerAdded` - the form usually isnt bothered with every click on every grand-child control.  To do that define a new Event (like `ItemClicked`) and raise it whenever.  The form can subscribe to those.

Comment: I Appreciate your help, i have done something like this..

Comment: The correct declaration would be `Public Event ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`  then just raise that event in the child click events...the form will have a new `UserControName.ItemClicked` event

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! that helped...